# libGLU.so.1 can't be found

Tags: software-installation

`ImportError: libGLU.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Please i got this error when i tried to install AutoDockTools. Please could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

On all current Ubuntu versions this library [is located](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGLU.so.1) in `libglu1-mesa` package.

You have to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa
```

Comment: Thanks but now says it needs libXmu